# Counting runs during play

Tags: cribbage

When playing Cribbage, if I played a 7, and my opponent played an 8, (making a 15 for 2 points), can I then play a 6 for a run of three, or do they have to be in consecutive order?

Answer (score 4):

According to this [site](http://www.bicyclecards.com/card-games/rule/cribbage) Yes it is a run.

> Example: Cards are played in this order: 9, 6, 8, 7. The dealer pegs 2 for fifteen when he plays the six and pegs 4 for run when he plays the seven (the 6, 7, 8, 9 sequence). The cards were not played in sequential order, but they form a true run with no foreign card.

I have seen written rules by Hoyle where they are required to be played in order, but every single web site I looked at allow for them to be out of order as long as they aren't interrupted with non-run cards.

Comment: *"According to Hoyle"* is **not** under copyright; anyone can publish a set of rules under that name.